# OData handling of collections and maps in queries/aggregations

Tags: list, dictionary, set, odata

The OData standard is pretty straight forward when it comes to doing queries and aggregations on fields, but I am having trouble wrapping my head around querying/aggregating against a field that is a collection or map.

For instance, lets say I have the following random class:

```
public class Teacher{
    public String name;
    public String city;
    public List<Class> classes;
    public Set<TeachingAssistant> TAs;
    public Map<Class,List<Student>> studentsPerClass;

    public Teacher(...){
        //init all variables
    }

}
```

Now, this is just an example.  For the purpose of this example, the teacher class is the only way to get at students, Tas, and Classes.  So, all of my queries and aggregations will need to be run off a collection of teachers.  With that in mind, I have some questions:

1. How do I do aggregations on the list of classes?  Like if I wanted to know the number of classes offered by a teacher, how would I do that in an OData query?

   For instance, I would like to do something like:

   ```
   .../Teachers?$apply=aggregate(classes with CountDistinct as totalClasses)
   ```

   or maybe:

   ```
   .../Teachers?$apply=aggregate(classes(*) with CountDistinct as totalClasses)
   ```

   Would either of these be the correct way?
2. If I want to query a specific item in a list or set, how do I access it?  A Set in java is not ordered and does not have anything for me to access it like `setName('<value>')`.  For lists, would I just have to say `listName('<num_index>')`?